# Smallest set of nonzero vectors in $\mathbb F_2^n$ which intersects every 2-dimensional subspace

Tags: co.combinatorics, graph-theory, finite-fields

What is the smallest set of nonzero vectors in $\mathbb F_2^n$ which intersects every 2-dimensional subspace?

For example, for *n* = 3, the set {001, 010, 011} does the job, and is minimal. For *n* = 4, {0001,0010,0011,1000,1001,1010,1011} does the job.

This is a special case of the Minimum Hitting Set problem (and [equivalently, Minimum Set Cover](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_cover_problem#Hitting_set_formulation)), which is known to be hard in general.  However, it is *such* a special case that I wonder if more can be said.  I have not had much luck finding existing results on the question, and trying to find the numbers by computer power does not seem easy, even for modest values of *n*.   My best results for $n$=5 and $n$=6 are sets of size 16 and 44, respectively, but I am not certain those are minimal.  That might suggest [A129045](http://oeis.org/A129045), but I know the answer for $n$=7 is much less than 134.

There are obvious generalizations – if you can answer the question for $k$-dimensional subspaces of $\mathbb F_q^n$, so much the better, but the particular case I have mentioned seems like a good starting point to me.

Most of all, I would appreciate links to existing literature!  Thanks.

Comment: A codimension one subspace intersects every 2-dimensional subspace nontrivially, so the minimal answer is certainly at most $2^{n-1}-1$

Comment: For the more general case, it might help to note that you are essentially asking for a covering of a $q$-Kneser graph with maximum independent sets. In particular this means that the number of vectors needed is at least the chromatic number of the corresponding graph. You can look here: https://arxiv.org/pdf/1806.00279.pdf

Answer (score 10):

$2^{n-1}-1$.

Let $H$ be a codimension one subspace of the $n$-dimensional vector space $V$. Then the intersection of $S$ with any $2$-dimensional subspace has dimension at least one, so that $H-0$ is a set of the kind you are asking about.

Conversely suppose that $S$ is a set of nonzero vectors intersecting every $2$-dimensional subspace. If $S$ does not have every nonzero vector in it, then say that it does not have $v$ and let $L$ be the one-dimensional subspace spanned by $v$. The image of $S$ in $V/L$ intersects every one-dimensional subspace nontrivially, so it has at least $2^{n-1}-1$ elements.

EDIT: More generally if $S$ is a set of nonzero vectors intersecting each $d$-dimensional subspace then $S$ has at least $2^{n-d+1}-1$ elements. Proof: Wlog $d$ is minimal. Choose a $(d-1)$-dimensional subspace $W$ of $V$ disjoint from $S$. The image of $S$ in $V/W$ has all the nonzero vectors. And this is best possible by taking $S$ to be the complement of $0$ in a vector subspace of codimension $d-1$.